# Bloqueio de login via bruteforce no php

Tags: php, aplicação-web, segurança

Tenho um sistema com captcha em meu site para tentar bloquear esse login, porém é muito incoveniente pois o usuário precisa fazê-lo toda vez que for logar, então

**Como mostrar o catpcha após N tentativas de login?**

Vi alguns exemplos com section e increment mas seria facilmente burlado apagando os cookies, algum exemplo de como fazer isso de outra forma mais segura?

Comment: nesse link tem um sistema de login anti-bruteforce http://www.devwilliam.com.br/php/sistema-de-login-com-ajax-e-php caso o numero de tentativas por ip exceda você pode adicionar/redirecionar para o captcha

Comment: Vi alguns comentários dizendo que via IP também ficaria vulneravel pois alguns bots trocam O ip constantemente enquanto fazem esse tipo de invasão.

Comment: força bruta é um assunto longo meu caro, o melhor a se fazer quando não há ajuda de um especialistas em segurança, é o bloqueio de ip, hash segura, intervalos entre as tentativas, captcha após um erro e assim vai...

Comment: Bom como o site é pequeno e tem pouca movimentação acredito que possa aguentar então, obrigado pela sugestão.